# display tr id on checkbox click when using multiple checkboxes in PHP foreach loop/array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this PHP/HTML Code:

```
$PortingStatuses = array('Submitted' => 'Y', 'Accepted' => 'Y', 'Rejected' => 'Y', 'Complete' => '', 'Cancelled' => '');
    foreach($PortingStatuses as $PortingStatus => $PortingChecked) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="PortingStatus" value="PortingStatus_'.$PortingStatus.'"';
        if($PortingChecked == 'Y') {
            echo 'checked="checked"';
        }
        echo '/> '.$PortingStatus.'';
```

it displays checkboxes for each item in the array (`$PortingStatuses`)

I have another foreach loop for my array items that displays:

```
foreach($PortingStatuses as $PortingStatus => $PortingChecked) {
    <tr id="PortingStatus_'.$PortingStatus.'">

    </tr>
}
```

how can i show/hide each tr on checkbox click/unclick?

Comment: add a click or change event to your checkboxes that will take the parent tr by using `closest('tr')` and then to hide the tr row use the `hide()` function.

Comment: why do you have many checkboxes with the same id `PortingStatus`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
<input type=checkbox class=hidetr value=1>
<input type=checkbox class=hidetr value=2>
...
<tr id=tr1>...</tr>
<tr id=tr2>...</tr>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.hidetr').on('click', function(){
        var trid = "tr" + $(this).val();
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
             $('#' + trid).show();
        }else{
             $('#' + trid).hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, it would be

```
$('#PortingStatus').click(function(){
    tr = this.value();
    if(this.checked==true)
        $('#'+tr+'').css('display','block');
    else
        $('#'+tr+'').css('display','none');     
});
```

Using Javascript:

```
function checkVal(elem){
    trId = elem.value;
    if(elem.checked == true)
        document.getElementById(''+trId+'').style.display='block'
    else
        document.getElementById(''+trId+'').style.display='none' 
}
```

in check box use this:
`<input type='checkbox' onclick='checkVal(this)'`